# properties of View Model are not set on HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

My View Model code:

```
public class Step2ViewModel : MultiStepBaseViewModel
{
    public IList<LayoutDetail> LayoutConfig { get; set; }
}
```

My View code:

```
@model eliteemail.Web.Mvc.Areas.Emails.ViewModels.Step2ViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Layout";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    for (int i = 0; i < @Model.LayoutConfig.Count(); i++)
    {
    <div class="grid_3 tcenter">
        <div class="divhighlight">
            <div style="width: 165px; margin: 6px auto 4px auto;" class="f16 bold tcenter" id="helptrigger1">@Model.LayoutConfig[i].LayoutTitle</div>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="layouts" href="@Model.LayoutConfig[i].LayoutImgPrev" title="1 Column">
                <img src="@Model.LayoutConfig[i].LayoutImg" alt="1 Column" width="189" height="227" vspace="5" />
            </a>
            <div style="width:189px; margin:auto">
                <input type="submit" class="button gobutton" style="margin-right: 40px; width: 165px;" value="Select" name="@Model.LayoutConfig[i].LayoutID,@Model.LayoutConfig[i].LayoutTitle"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    } 
}
```

My Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Step2()
{
    Step2BusinessLogic step2BusinessLogic = new Step2BusinessLogic();
    Step2ViewModel step2ViewModel = step2BusinessLogic.CreateStep2ViewModel();
    return View(step2ViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step2(Step2ViewModel step2ViewModel)
{
    ....
}
```

My Business Logic Class code:

```
public class Step2BusinessLogic
{
    public Step2ViewModel CreateStep2ViewModel(string Id)
    {
        Step2ViewModel step2ViewModel = new Step2ViewModel();
        step2ViewModel.MultiStepId = new Guid(Id);
        step2ViewModel.LayoutConfig = GetLayout();
        return createEmailStep2ViewModel;
    }

    public List<LayoutDetail> GetLayout()
    {
        List<LayoutDetail> layoutList = new List<LayoutDetail>();

        LayoutDetail layout1 = new LayoutDetail();
        layout1.LayoutID = 1;
        layout1.LayoutTitle = "1 Column";
        layout1.LayoutImg = "~/img/create/layout/layout-1.png";
        layout1.LayoutImgPrev = "img/create/layout/layout-1-preview.png";
        layoutList.Add(layout1);

        LayoutDetail layout2 = new LayoutDetail();
        layout2.LayoutID = 2;
        layout2.LayoutTitle = "1:2 Column";
        layout2.LayoutImg = "~/img/create/layout/layout-2.png";
        layout2.LayoutImgPrev = "img/create/layout/layout-2-preview.png";
        layoutList.Add(layout2);

        .........(12 Items)

        return layoutList;
    }
}

public class LayoutDetail
{
    public int LayoutID { get; set; }

    public string LayoutTitle { get; set; }

    public string LayoutImg { get; set; }

    public string LayoutImgPrev { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that when I submit from `Step2View.cshtml`, then

```
public ActionResult Step2(Step2ViewModel step2ViewModel)
```

is being called but the properties of `step2ViewModel` are not being set and `ModelState.IsValid` is returning false. I want to avoid both conditions. Any help please, as I am very new to MVC.

I searched several links but can't understand the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not submitting anything when you do the post.  You have no form elements other than a button.  If you had form elements, then the data would be passed back.  Try adding an 
`@Html.HiddenFor(o=>o.LayoutID)` in your view and then posting again.  The form will post back hidden elements or form fields, but not display only fields as you are doing.

Comment: i think you did not get my question..
in my Step2() Action handler when i return View(step2ViewModel); at that time my step2ViewModel has some properties populated with value
 but when i am trying to get that step2ViewModel in my Step2(Step2ViewModel step2ViewModel) i am unable to get values of properties of my step2ViewModel

Comment: You populate the properties in the model, but what I am saying is that in MVC, they WILL NOT be posted back unless they are form fields such as when you do 'EditorFor' or 'DropDownListFor'.  Things are not automatically passed back in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a `foreach` loop on a collection object as the model binder cannot work with it. Use a `for-loop` instead. In your code replace each occurence of `@item` with `@Model.LayoutConfig[i]`, see updated code below:

```
for(var i=0;i<@Model.LayoutConfig.Count();i++)
{
    <div class="grid_3 tcenter">
        <div class="divhighlight">
            <div style="width: 165px; margin: 6px auto 4px auto;" class="f16 bold tcenter" id="helptrigger1">@Model.LayoutConfig[i].LayoutTitle</div>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="layouts" href="@Model.LayoutConfig[i].LayoutImgPrev" title="1 Column">
                <img src=@Model.LayoutConfig[i].LayoutImg" alt="1 Column" width="189" height="227" vspace="5" />
            </a>
            <div style="width:189px; margin:auto">
                <input type="submit" class="button gobutton" style="margin-right: 40px; width: 165px;" value="Select" name="@Model.LayoutConfig[i].LayoutID, @Model.LayoutConfig[i].LayoutTitle"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: i Did that but there was same result

my problem is other than it

Comment: If you did then can you edit your question and update the view and post the code exactly as you have it.